# Agilizar proceso de geocodificación inversa en R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr, geocodificación

Estoy usando la función  reverse_geo() para obtener los departamentos a los que pertenece una lista de pozos petroleros. El problema es que hay 80 mil pozos y el proceso se vuelve muy lento. Entonces, para acelerar la búsqueda me gustaría obtener solo la *subregión* ya que es el único dato que necesito. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Mi código es

```
library(readxl)
info_pozos <- read_excel("C:/Users/Kevin/Downloads/info_pozos.xlsx")


library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidygeocoder)

reverse <- info_pozos %>%
reverse_geocode(lat = coordenaday, long = coordenadax, method = 'arcgis',
address = address_found, full_results = FALSE)

View(reverse)
```

El link del dataset es: http://datos.energia.gob.ar/dataset/c846e79c-026c-4040-897f-1ad3543b407c/archivo/cbfa4d79-ffb3-4096-bab5-eb0dde9a8385

Comment: Lamentablemente no es fácil optimizar el proceso, cada fila es una coordenada a la que hay que georeferenciar por lo que hay que hacer la llamada a la API, además por el volumen tal vez haya limitaciones en cantidad de llamadas a la API. Una posible optimización, podría ser agrupar coordenadas en áreas de  1 o más kilómetros, dónde podrías consultar por el centro de dicha área y resolviste varios pozos con una sola llamada. Desarrollar esta optimización es complicado, tal vez te lleve más tiempo que dejar funcionado tu script el tiempo que necesite.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho encontré la solución, básicamente consiste en hacer un merge espacial (desconocía esa posibilidad).